Python stable-baselines SAC.load(path) returns error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main       
    run()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file   
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.8.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Workspace\Financial\online_trader.py", line 752, in <module>
    model.load(f"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Workspace\\Financial\\MODELS\\dqn2\\DQN_model_189",env=vec_env)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py", line 741, in load
    model.set_parameters(params, exact_match=True, device=device)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py", line 629, in set_parameters
    attr.load_state_dict(params[name], strict=exact_match)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load_state_dict'

I try to load a saved SAC model but the model load have a problem like this.
Model generation:
 model = SAC('MultiInputPolicy', vec_env, gamma=best_params['gamma'], learning_rate=best_params['learning_rate'], buffer_size=best_params['buffer_size'], batch_size=best_params['batch_size'], ent_coef="auto_0.1", policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=tensorboard_log_dir+"TRY_2_")

model.save(location)

model.load(location)

